# Detect calls to certain C functions

Tags: c++, clang

In a large code base, I want to find all calls to a certain set of functions.  Clang's `deprecated` and `unavailable` attributes don't quite do what I want, at least as of the Apple LLVM-6.0 version.  Example:

```
__attribute__((deprecated)) void A();
__attribute__((deprecated)) void B();
void C();

void A()
{
    B();
}

void B()
{
    A();
}

void C()
{
    A();
    B();
}
```

The compiler gives warnings about the calls to A and B from C, but not the call of A to B or vice versa.

There are many of the functions in question, so it doesn't seem practical to just comment out declarations one by one.

Comment: Are you using an IDE? apparently Visual Studio can show all calls to a function, maybe some others can too

Comment: I've found that backtrace would help in these situations when looking for function calls - I'm not sure what environment you are working in but this might be of some help: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/backtrace.3.html

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you are trying to accomplish, however,  gcc, with parameters: '-Wall -Wextra -pedantic' issued a warning about every call to function A() and every call to function B()

Comment: @MattMcNabb, I am using Xcode 4.6.3 on Mac OS X 10.7.  I also use Visual Studio 2010 Express on Windows Vista.   However, there are hundreds of these functions, so just being able to find all calls to one function won't help much.

Comment: @user3629249, that's not the case for the version of gcc that Apple supplies.

Comment: Note: These are no valid prototypes. omitting `void` for "no args" should result in a warning since C99 at least.

Comment: @Olaf, I'm actually compiling as C++.

Comment: So why do you tag the question then C? These are **different** languages! You would not add Python or COBOL tags, either, wouldn't you?

Comment: XCode is currently at version 6.4 or thereabouts, and Mac OS X is at version 10.10.4.  Is there a reason you have to use such old code on such an old version of Mac OS X?  Both are well out of support by now.

Comment: If you put those functions in a shared library, you can use LD_PRELOAD (Linux) or, I hear,  DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES (Apple) to replace them at runtime with wrappers that can call the original via dlsym.

Comment: Am I missing something or would a simple text search of the code-base suffice?

Comment: @Galik, same thought here. I would leverage a script ( rep, perl, etc.). Much of the discussion seems to be over-kill

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason for not warning about the call to `A()` from within `B()` and the call to `B()` from within `A()` is that those calls are in the bodies of deprecated functions.  Since the functions themselves are deprecated, there isn't a lot of virtue in reporting on deprecated calls made within those functions; omitting those errors avoids some 'false positives'.  When you eliminate the deprecated functions, there won't be a problem with the calls from within them.

I compiled a mildly modified version of your code with XCode 6.4 — running `gcc --version` yielded:

```
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.53) (based on LLVM 3.6.0svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.4.0
Thread model: posix
```

Code `unavailable.c`:

```
__attribute__((deprecated)) void A(void);
__attribute__((deprecated)) void B(void);
void C(void);

void A(void)
{
    B();
}

void B(void)
{
    A();
}

void C(void)
{
    A();
    B();
}
```

Compilation:

```
$ make unavailable.o
gcc -O3 -g -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes  -Wold-style-definition -c unavailable.c
unavailable.c:17:5: error: 'A' is deprecated [-Werror,-Wdeprecated-declarations]
    A();
    ^
unavailable.c:5:6: note: 'A' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
void A(void)
     ^
unavailable.c:18:5: error: 'B' is deprecated [-Werror,-Wdeprecated-declarations]
    B();
    ^
unavailable.c:10:6: note: 'B' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
void B(void)
     ^
2 errors generated.
rmk: error code 1
$
```

I had to add the `void` parameters to the C functions because in C, a function declared `void C();` has no prototype — `C` is a function that takes an unspecified (but not variadic) argument list and returns no value.  (The 'not variadic' bit means it does not have ellipsis `...` at the end of the argument list. You must always have a prototype in scope before calling such a function.)

Comment: I can see how the Clang writers might think that "there isn't a lot of virtue in reporting on deprecated calls made within those functions", but in my case the functions aren't literally deprecated, I just hoped that this might be a trick to find all these calls.

Comment: Either deal with one function at a time, or accept that you will not get reports of uses of the functions marked as deprecated from calls in other functions which are themselves marked as deprecated.  You will need to spot the 'deprecated call from within deprecated function' operations separately.  Doesn't XCode have decent code search capabilities?  (I have XCode, but I only really use the command line compilers — I've yet to find an IDE I like.)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up writing a little program to search for the calls that were missed by the `__attribute__((unavailable))` trick.